# Adobe Lightroom presets in react application

Tags: android, ios, flutter, react-native, lightroom

I have few .DNG files and I wanted to use them as a preset for an application. The DNG files are edited from Adobe Lightroom. I wanted to use the same presets for my filter app which I am developing.

Thank you.

I tried using different xmp to image snippets, but I am unable to have any luck yet.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.